# New Version of Tweetinvi Creating some issues

Tags: twitter-oauth, tweetinvi

before update am using tweetinvi 0.9.07 and it works fine when I update it with the latest version it will generate several errors which are in snapshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tweetinvi credentials has changed in version 0.9.9.x.

You can find the documentation regarding this [here](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Credentials).

- `TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials` **has changed to** `Auth.SetUserCredentials`.
- `TwitterCredentials.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials` **has changed to** `Auth.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials`.

Also please note that `Auth.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials` uses the credentials defined by creds. You therefore do not need to call `Auth.SetUserCredentials` inside a lambda of `ExecuteOperationWithCredentials`.

Finally please note that you can now create credentials via the `new TwitterCredentials(...)`.